# Parse complex HTML into Android TextView

Tags: android, html, textview

I have an adapter that have to show HTML content obtained from a server, but I can't use a WebView for each adapter item because performance is terrible...

I think that the only possible solution is to parse each HTML into a TextView.

It looks like that in iOS, DTCoreText library achieves this. Is there any similar library in Android? Html.fromHtml() supports only some tags, and I need to show elements as lists, tables, embedded images and videos, emojis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half of what you cite (tables, embedded videos) is not supported by `TextView`, regardless of how you create the `Spannable` to show in it.

Hence, use `WebView`. Using a `WebView` as an "adapter item" is unlikely to work well; use one `WebView` for the entire content that you wish to display.

Or, use actual Android layouts for the various pieces, rather than trying to pretend that a `TextView` is a Web rendering component. Getting the videos to work may be tricky.

Comment: I have to keep each html content separated so I suppose #2 @CommonsWare solution is the only way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @Carles: I'm not sure whether `VideoView` will work well in an `AdapterView` or `RecyclerView`, as `VideoView` is based on `SurfaceView`, and that has issues with animations. You may need to use a `TextureView` and `MediaPlayer`, assuming that you want the videos actually inline in the adapter-based layout. Personally, I think that will result in videos that are a bit small, so I'd recommend perhaps showing a thumbnail in an `ImageView` and launching into a separate full-screen video player for actual playback, but that's just me.